# Angularjs Binding 2 directives scope models to a parent controllers models

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a form controller with 2 object models  model1:{name:"foo"} model2:{name:"model2"} 
I created 2 directives (both which create isolated scopes) . One with Element only binding which uses model1  and another one with Attribute only binding  which uses model2.

The nesting is like so:

```
 <div myattibute="model2">
   <mytag my-model="model"></mytag>
 </div>
```

The attribute only directive doesn't have a template and the tag directive has a template.

The problem is that I am getting undefined in mytag directive for the model.

**1**.Can someone see the problem and explain it in the plnkr ?

http://plnkr.co/edit/Q23XqY?p=preview

---

**Partial Solution:**
A working example with adding an empty div template with just ng-transclude for the myattribute directive makes it work. With i mandated that this attribute directive is on a div it that I would have wanted it to be placeable on any div, span etc.
Here is the working example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/z0M5ys?p=preview

**2**.How is ng-transclude affecting scope inheritance?
**3**.Can't I create this attribute with only business logic without any markup ?

Answer (score 1):

Isolate scopes are best avoided except for rare cases they add unnecessary complexity. It is much simpler to just use $scope.$watch to bind to expressions in attributes like this:

```
$scope.$watch(attrs.myModel, function(newValue, oldValue) {})

$scope.$watch(attrs.myattribute, function(newValue, oldValue) {})
```

This way your directives can either share the parent scope they were declared in and handle binding to it using $watch expressions, or they can create a child scope using `{ scope: true }` if needed.

Here is one possible solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/mm2q67?p=preview

Keep in mind that your `myTag` directive *can* use an isolate scope if you'd really like to do it that way, but the `myattribute` one can't as that will break the scope inheritance chain for `myTag`

Comment: interesting point. What I am trying to achieve is hierarchical components . For example a component can contain only layout information for other components inside it and attributes are for extra business UI logic without presentation. Do you think your model will fit ? (because as you can see, even in a simple example I ran into some problems with '=' binding)

Comment: There isn't much you absolutely need isolate scopes for. The Angular core almost never uses them anywhere. Not to say you would never want them, but it usually isn't necessary. Take a look at how directive controllers work as well. You can have one root controller that your "child" directives can have a reference too and interact with the root with. ngForm and ngModel directives do this.

Comment: Oh also you should consider that your directive *should* generally be mostly presentation logic and the business logic should live in the services. Directives are free to use those services of course.